# bash & s3cmd not working properly

Tags: linux, bash, shell, amazon-s3, s3cmd

Hi I have a shell script which contains s3cmd command on ubuntu 12.04 LTS.
I configured cron for this shell script which works fine for local environment but don't push the file to s3. But when i run shell script manually, It pushes the file to s3 without any error. I checked log and found nothing for this. Here is my shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash
User="abc"
datab="abc_xyz"
pass="abc@123"
Host="abc1db.instance.com"
FILE="abc_rds`date +%d_%b_%Y`.tar.gz"
S3_BKP_PATH="s3://abc/db/"

cd /abc/xyz/scripts/

mysqldump -u $User $datab -h $Host -p$pass | gzip -c > $FILE | tee -a /abc/xyz/logs/app-bkp.log

s3cmd --recursive put /abc/xyz/scripts/$FILE  $S3_BKP_PATH | tee -a /abc/xyz/logs/app-bkp.log

mv /abc/xyz/scripts/$FILE /abc/xyz/backup2015/Database/

#END
```

This is really weird. Any suggestion would be a great help.

Comment: Having same issue now, did you get it working?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the user running configured in crontab has correct permissions and keys in the environment.

I am guessing the keys are configured in env file as they are not here in the script.

Comment: I have added this cron as root user and also if i run the same shell script as a root user it works fine. It transfers data to s3 bucket.

Comment: Is the cronjob running? Can you share crontab entry for the script?

Comment: Below is the crontab entry for this shell script. 
45 23 * * * /bin/bash /abc/xyz/scripts/rds_bkp.sh > /dev/null 2>&1

Comment: Just a thought: Can you remove "/bin/bash" and rather make the script executable ?

Comment: Made changes as suggested. But for your information, Script executes successfully in crontab it just don't send the backup to s3 bucket while if run script manually it sends backup to s3 bucket.

Comment: Also, if you write everything to /dev/null including error - you cannot find any logs

Comment: Is "s3cmd" on your path ?

Comment: Thanks for the comment on /dev/null and Yes s3cmd is on my path. Its location is /usr/bin/s3cmd and configured fully. About the keys. It wouldn't have worked if there was problem with keys in manual shell script run.

Comment: Keys part was before you confirmed for the user.